# How to send data to an EventHub setting the PartitionId NOT the PartitionKey (Python)

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I saw at Microsoft Docs that there is a way to send data to the partition I want by setting the PartitionId instead of the PartitionKey (using C#).

> CreatePartitionSender(String)  Create a PartitionSender which can
>   publish EventData's directly to a specific EventHub partition.

However, I couldn't find the same in Python.

Is any available way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to send data to Azure Event Hubs, which are HTTP REST API and AMQP 1.0 protocol.

For using HTTP REST API or [Azure EventHub Python Client Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python), only `partitionId` parameter supports to send a new event to a specified partition in an Event Hub, as the two below.

1. The REST API [`Send partition event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-partition-event) requires the `partitionId` parameter in the endpoint `https://{servicebusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/partitions/{partitionId}/messages`, and it's the only one REST API to support the feature of send partition。
2. The source code comment of `Sender.py` explains the [`partition`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/sender.py#L32) parameter as below.

   ```
   :param partition: The specific partition ID to send to. Default is None, in which case the service
    will assign to all partitions using round-robin.
   :type partition: str
   ```

So actually, you can not use `partitionKey` value to send an event to a specified EventHub partition, except using AMQP 1.0 in Python. For using AMQP 1.0, please see the offical document [`AMQP 1.0 in Azure Service Bus and Event Hubs protocol guide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fevent-hubs%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) and search for the words `partition-key` on the page, the result as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure but using python  , here is the method for opening connection

```
def open(self):
        """
        Open the Sender using the supplied conneciton.
        If the handler has previously been redirected, the redirect
        context will be used to create a new handler before opening it.
        :param connection: The underlying client shared connection.
        :type: connection: ~uamqp.connection.Connection
        """
        self.running = True
        if self.redirected:
            self.target = self.redirected.address
            self._handler = SendClient(
                self.target,
                auth=self.client.get_auth(),
                debug=self.client.debug,
                msg_timeout=self.timeout,
                error_policy=self.retry_policy,
                keep_alive_interval=self.keep_alive,
                client_name=self.name,
                properties=self.client.create_properties())
        self._handler.open()
        while not self._handler.client_ready():
            time.sleep(0.05)
```

and here is the **Init**

```
def __init__(self, client, target, partition=None, send_timeout=60, keep_alive=None, auto_reconnect=True):
        """
        Instantiate an EventHub event Sender handler.
        :param client: The parent EventHubClient.
        :type client: ~azure.eventhub.client.EventHubClient.
        :param target: The URI of the EventHub to send to.
        :type target: str
        :param partition: The specific partition ID to send to. Default is None, in which case the service
         will assign to all partitions using round-robin.
        :type partition: str
        :param send_timeout: The timeout in seconds for an individual event to be sent from the time that it is
         queued. Default value is 60 seconds. If set to 0, there will be no timeout.
        :type send_timeout: int
        :param keep_alive: The time interval in seconds between pinging the connection to keep it alive during
         periods of inactivity. The default value is None, i.e. no keep alive pings.
        :type keep_alive: int
        :param auto_reconnect: Whether to automatically reconnect the sender if a retryable error occurs.
         Default value is `True`.
        :type auto_reconnect: bool
        """
        self.running = False
        self.client = client
        self.target = target
        self.partition = partition
        self.timeout = send_timeout
        self.redirected = None
        self.error = None
        self.keep_alive = keep_alive
        self.auto_reconnect = auto_reconnect
        self.retry_policy = errors.ErrorPolicy(max_retries=3, on_error=_error_handler)
        self.reconnect_backoff = 1
        self.name = "EHSender-{}".format(uuid.uuid4())
        if partition:
            self.target += "/Partitions/" + partition
            self.name += "-partition{}".format(partition)
        self._handler = SendClient(
            self.target,
            auth=self.client.get_auth(),
            debug=self.client.debug,
            msg_timeout=self.timeout,
            error_policy=self.retry_policy,
            keep_alive_interval=self.keep_alive,
            client_name=self.name,
            properties=self.client.create_properties())
        self._outcome = None
        self._condition = None
```

I believe , below line of function will create a partition sender only

```
if partition:
                self.target += "/Partitions/" + partition
                self.name += "-partition{}".format(partition)
```

**Reference**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/sender.py

Hope it helps.